# Will this work if I'm using an anti-static wrist strap when repairing a laptop?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, power, repair, laptop

I was thinking that I would connect it to the ground terminal of the outlet (I live in India so it's the top one) but I'm scared of getting shocked because of a faulty ground point etc. So I was thinking if I take a 3-prong DC adapter (it's like 5V) that I have lying around, cut out the wire and insulate the other 2 wires and connect the strap and mat to it.

Will that work?

And is there any way to check if ground connection is working or not (I have a multi meter just in case)?

Comment: Remember that the thing you need to be grounded to is the laptop, not necessarily earth ground. If you can clip your ground strap to a ground on the laptop, that might be good enough.

Comment: I don't know about your particular grounding strap, but many come with internal resistance that would prevent electrocution.

Comment: @Hearth -- So what if he's grounded to the laptop, and picks it up, and walks across a shag carpet, picking up 10,000 volts, charging up both the laptop and him? I would rather ground both to a copper water pipe. Are there any problems with that?

Comment: @MicroservicesOnDDD, as long as the person and the device are at the *same* potential, there is no net difference in voltage. Ever see a demo where a person sits in a cage connected to a 2 MV Van de Graaf generator? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vheyKyV8vSA

Comment: As @MathKeepsMeBusy states, a ground strap absolutely *must* have a series resistor for personal safety! Check with an ohmmeter -- should be in the realm of 200 kΩ - 5 MΩ or so.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik -- Yes, but we are not talking about a faraday cage here.  We have to protect against multiple charge/discharge scenarios, including outside charged persons entering the scenario. If the OP charges themselves and laptop up, then places laptop down, the discharge would go through the part of the laptop first touching the place where it is being laid down. If laptop is open because it is being fixed, and parts are hanging out, that could be bad, depending on how much the laptop+worker system has been charged up.

Comment: Remember, too, that laptops are not always connected!

Answer (score 1):

Static dissipative (anti-static) systems are based on voltage/charge equalization to reduce the effects of electro-static discharge (ESD). Having a zero volt (ground) connection is nice but not necessary.

The idea is to have a medium-high resistance between ground, your body and the equipment you are working with.

Static dissipative mats have a resistivity between 200kΩ and 5MΩ per square. This allows the voltage/charge to equalize across the surface with a low current.

Do not ground the mat. If charge equalization to ground is required, then a 1MΩ must be placed in series as close to the ground connection as possible.

In my opinion, the static dissipative mat is more important that the wrist strap. Static aquired by walking away from the repair and returning is easily equalized by touching the mat before touching the equipment.

The static dissiptive wrist strap must have a 1MΩ resistor in series with the connector. This allows the connection to be made directly to the equipment or the mat.

The wrist strap does not provide personal safety. If you touch a dangerous voltage with any part of your body, you will not be protected by the strap. It is for the protection of the equipment only.

> I was thinking that I would connect it to the ground terminal of the outlet

Connecting the wrist strap to ground does not necessarily solve the problem if the equipment is floating. Touching the equipment can still result in an ESD event. **Do not** connect the wriststrap to ground. Connect the strap to the equipment directly or through a mat. Be certain the strap has a 1MΩ resistor in it.

> So I was thinking if I take a 3-prong DC adapter (it's like 5V) that I have lying around, cut out the wire and insulate the other 2 wires and connect the strap and mat to it.

Local electrical code may not like this. Do not connect this wire directly to the mat or wrist strap. You must use a 1MΩ resistor in series with this wire.

> Will that work?

Not for static dissipation.

> And is there any way to check if ground connection is working or not (I have a multi meter just in case)?

It is not a good idea to measure resistance on a live system. You should call an electrician to verify the ground integrity. If you know what your doing then you probably don't need my advice.

Be clear. Having the equipment at zero volts (ground potential) is not the goal and will not necessarily protect against ESD. Having zero volts between you and the equipment is the goal.

---

From the comments under the question:

> We have to protect against multiple charge/discharge scenarios, including outside charged persons entering the scenario.

Have them touch the mat.

> If the OP charges themselves and laptop up, then places laptop down, the discharge would go through the part of the laptop first touching the place where it is being laid down. If laptop is open because it is being fixed, and parts are hanging out, that could be bad,

No technician worth their salt would do that. Leave the equipment on the mat until it is reassembled.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to use a 3 pin fan connector in a computer, and ground the mat through the black wire, you would be 'half-way grounded' to the chassis or fully, if the chassis in turn is connected to the utility ground.

With your MM, measure from utility ground to a sink or any piping. If it's 0 V, you *should* be good to go, since I have no idea how good / bad your electrical wiring is.

Comment: Please clarify. Not sure what you are trying to say. "you would be half-way grounded or completely"